# Box element not centered on CSS

Tags: css, sass

I'm designing my website, and I have a problem with the positioning a box, in CSS. When you see it from the desktop it looks good, but at the moment of the phone it is not totally responsive, nor centered. I do not understand what is wrong with my code.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="cuadrado">
  <div class="franja">    
  <h1>Mario</h1>
  <h4>Web Developer</h4>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cuadrado {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 50px;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
height: 500px;
width: 462px;
border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
border: 0px none #000000;
}

.foto {
    position: relative;
    left: 190px;
    top: -125px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 100% auto;

}

.franja {
    position: relative;
    top: 62px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EFF2F2;
  }
```

Here you can see it online: https://mariomuratori.github.io/contact

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please create a code snippet of your code. thanks

Comment: Yes, your question needs to be self-contained here, with relevant HTML and CSS. I doubt many will clone from github simply to respond to a forum question (especially with v. limited details).

Comment: One piece of advice is that you can just put `border-radius: 8px`, you do not have to repeat the value four times.

Comment: you have to share working snippet to understand the issue.

Comment: I do not understand. I already shared a fragment of my code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't look as good on your phone is because you're using static pixels, and the resolution on your phone is not the same as your monitor.

You can try checking out a tutorial like this for help to make it responsive on both devices:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp